# SQL - Failed to convert string to Int32

Tags: c#, sql

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlParameter[] pram = new SqlParameter[7];
    pram[0] = new SqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    pram[1] = new SqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    pram[2] = new SqlParameter("@dob", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    pram[3] = new SqlParameter("@gender", SqlDbType.Char, 10);
    pram[4] = new SqlParameter("@fathername", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    pram[5] = new SqlParameter("@contact", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
    pram[6] = new SqlParameter("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

    pram[0].Value = fname;
    pram[1].Value = lname;
    pram[2].Value = dob;
    pram[3].Value = gender;
    pram[4].Value = fathername;
    pram[5].Value = contact;
    pram[6].Value = address;

    for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
    }
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex_msg)
{
    string msg = "Error occured while inserting";
    msg += ex_msg.Message;
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Error received:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Comment: what is your error ? and provide full function include query

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Comment: Check with "pram[5].Value = contact;" . whether it is correct integer or not . If it is NULL then also your code will give error to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably passing a value that can't be parsed into an `int` for this parameter:

```
pram[5] = new SqlParameter("@contact", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
```

Check what you are passing here:

```
pram[5].Value = contact;
```

If contact is a string then do something like:

```
int contactNumber;
pram[5].Value = int.TryParse(contact, out contactNumber) ? contactNumber : 0;
```

Comment: Ya because your value can't be parsed into an int - check that you are really passing in`contact` what you expect :)

Comment: nope am still confused as am begineer am not getting it

Comment: @SAKET - what is the type of `contract`? Can you show what value you have in it please?

Comment: @SAKET - mobile numbers usually start with `0` or have other characters besides numbers so I'd recommend that you save it as a `varchar` in the DB and not an `Int32` like you currently do